# How to remove a class name that has a counter

Tags: jquery

I'm setting up a invoice form. Every time I click on a button the `addItem` function creates `<li>` elements with a class name `element+counter`.
Add the same time it also creates a delete button next to it that also has the 'element+counter' as class name.

Every time I add a element the counter increases.

But how do I remove a specific `element+counter` line with the delete button?

```js
var verwijderCounter = 0;

function addItems(){
verwijderCounter++;

$("#description").append("<li class='element"+verwijderCounter+"'>"+$('#formOmschrijving').val()+"</li>");
$("#uurprijs").append("<li class='element"+verwijderCounter+"'>"+$('#formUurprijs').val()+"</li>");
      
$("#amount").append("<li class='element"+verwijderCounter+"'>"+$('#formUren').val()+"</li>");
$("#removeLine").append('<button type="button" class="btn verwijder element'+verwijderCounter+'">del</button>');
```

Comment: on button click you have to call a function which will remove that particular row. in that function decrease the counter as well

Comment: Also it seems that you are repeating id's on each addition. that's incorrect practice and those repeated id's will not work when you try to use them in jquery [they will always refer to the first one]. So use class instead

Comment: @Alive to Die is correct. your design using id seems to be a wrong approach. however, the solution might be to find the enclosing parent element (e.g. table row or a ul) and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the delete button let it know the counter:

I didn't test but it should be roughly like this:

```
$("#removeLine").append('<button id="delete"'+verwijderCounter+' type="button" class="btn verwijder element'+verwijderCounter+'">del</button>');
$( "#delete" + verwijderCounter).click(function() {
  removeItems(verwijderCounter);
});
```

And then remove all elements with the same class with this:

```
function removeItems(counter) {
   $( 'element"+counter ).remove();
}
```

And do not decrease the counter because it will mess up your class-names!